# Mocking a function of an already instantiated python class

Tags: python, mocking

I have an instance of a class.

MyClass.py:

```
class MyClass:
    def f1(self):
        print 'f1'
        self.f2()

    def f2(self):
        print 'f2'

myInstance = MyClass()
```

If I call `myInstance.f1()` I get:

```
f1
f2
```

In my test class, I want to change the behaviour of `f2()`, without creating a new instance of `myInstance`, or touching `f1()`. So I would like to set `f2()` in my test class, so that when I run:

TestMyClass.py:

```
from MyClass import myInstance

# I don't know what goes here...
def f2(self):
    print 'mock_f2'

myInstance.f1()
```

It prints:

```
f1
mock_f2
```

How do I do this? All of the instructions I've seen online require me to create a new instance of `MyClass` and do stuff to that.

Answer (score 0):

In python you can set a method like an attribute.

```
def f2():
    print "mock f2"
class A(object):
    def f1(self):
        print "f1"
        self.f2()

    def f2(self):
        print "f2"
a = A()
# prints
# f1
# f2
a.f1()
a.f2 = f2
# prints
# f1
# mock f2
a.f1()
```

Doing so will set the method at the object level, meaning that if you instantiate another object, it will not be affected.

```
b = A()
# prints
# f1
# f2    
b.f1()
```